# Chrome extension using Google Drive API

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

I am trying to get a google extension to use the Google Drive api.

I haven't published the extension so far and am struggling to work out what the value of the key and the client_id should be in the manifest.

```
"permissions": ["https://www.googleapis.com/","https://accounts.google.com/","identity"],
  "background":{
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "?????",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
    ]
  },
key:"????"
```

I tried the instructions in this article:

https://medium.com/swlh/oauth2-openid-chrome-extension-login-system-29285323882f

This suggests that the key can be found by looking at the "id" field of the extension in chrome://extensions. I can then go to Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/{id} and I can use the key in the manifest in there.

I have tried getting the client_id by going to the google developer's console https://console.developers.google.com/ where I have created a project and enabled the Drive API. I then go into the Google Drive API screen and create an "Web application" OAuth 2 credential and I have copied the client_id here to the oauth section of the manifest but when I make a call to chrome.identity.getAuthToken, I get this error in chrome.runtime.lastError

OAuth2 request failed: Service responded with error: 'bad client id: {0}'

Is the google developer's console the correct place to generate the client_id for a chrome extension? There's a warning that says "To protect you and your users, your consent screen and application need to be verified by Google". It's an extension not an application so I guess I am in the wrong place.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Medium Article**

I would recommend the Google's method since it's a lot less configuration, but to get the property values its noting you can do the following:

The `key` is found by:

1. Packing the chrome extension
2. Dragging the .crx file into `chrome://extensions`
3. Navigating in windows file explorer to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\<packed-extension-id>\`
4. Open the `manifest.json`
5. Copy the `key` value and add it to your extension.

The article then states you need to remove the packed extension and load your unpacked dev extension.

For the `client_id` you need to create a new OAuth Client ID (Web Application) and add a redirect URI in the following structure:
`https://<extension-id>.chromiumapp.org`.
This can then be added to the manifest.json.

I would also make sure to configure your consent screen to add Google Drive which will be a sensitive permission. As long as you use your Google account in the extension you shouldn't need to go through the verification process.

**Google Example**

Here is a more in depth walkthrough in order to get OAuth working within a Chrome Extension:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/tut_oauth/

Essentially you need to upload your extension as a draft in the Chrome Developer Dashboard. Once it is uploaded (it can remain a draft), it will create an Item ID within the web store.

You will also find the `public key` in the Package section of the uploaded item this will be the `key` value in the manifest.

You can then configure a project in the Google Cloud Console with a new OAuth Client ID (Chrome App) and link to the web store URL with the Item ID. Once saved you can now add the associated `client_id` value to the manifest.

Comment: The medium article says you can “faux register” the extension. It also says that in the cloud console it should be a web application not a chrome app.

Comment: Interesting. I went through the article and added what they wanted for the `key` and `client_id`. I would recommend Google's example since it doesn't require you configuring an auth endpoint which also may be a cause of it not working as you intend.

Comment: In the google article, it says that you should create the OAuth client ID as a Chrome App but you say above that it should be a Web Application. If it is a Chrome App, you have to give it an Application ID which is the Last part of your app's Chrome Web Store URL. If it is a Web Application, it's a redirect url.

Comment: I went through the google example and it will works. thanks.

Comment: mv2 is now obsoleted, the new url is https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/tut_oauth/